# How to make the page's params redirect to another page still work

Tags: apex, visualforce, redirect

i have two params in apex,
ex:

```
errorNum = 1;
errorMessage = System.Label.UPL_OFFMSG_OfferExist;
```

now,i want to redirect from the current page to another,but the param will lost in the next page.

please help.

Comment: Try to use the same controller in both pages and `setRedirect(false)` [More info](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The key to this is to use the `PageReference` class and in particular the `getParameters()` method.

I will make the presumption that the page you are trying to redirect to is a VF page called NextPage.

The first step is to get a PageReference reference for that page using `PageReference pr = Page.NextPage;`

You can now make use of the goodness of the PageReference class as [documented](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_list.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) in the Salesforce docs.

The method that we're interested in is the [getParameters()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_list.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) method. As you can see from the documentation this returns a map of parameters that you can add to. Which means you can add your variables to the map to make sure they are passed as parameters in the URL:

```
pr.getParameters().put('errorNum', errorNum);
pr.getParameters().put('errorMessage', errorMessage);
```

The PageReference class then converts these parameters to Key Value pairs in the query string of the URL that it builds.

If you want to force the browser to do a client side redirect (use GET rather than POST) then use `pr.setRedirect(true);` and then return the Page Reference from your method.

A small note: If you're redirecting to an external page you will need to construct the PageReference by using the target URL. And in this case the browser will always be forced to do a redirect, so `setRedirect` become superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Pagereference p=new Pagereference('/apex/samplepage2?errorNum =1&errorMessage =System.Label.UPL_OFFMSG_OfferExist');
    p.setredirect(true);

    return p;
```

Pass as a query param as illustrated above

Comment: I think you should remove & symbol before errorNum parameter. I think that is a typo

Comment: i have done that

Comment: thanks !Should work i feel ?Whats your thought?

Comment: Actually original string was ('/apex/samplepage2?&errorNum =1&errorMessage =System.Label.UPL_OFFMSG_OfferExist');. I edited your answer and removed & appearing after ?.

Comment: right !It was type from my side !My bad